# Failed to re-build pycurl with OpenSSL

Tags: python, ubuntu, openssl, pycurl, gnutls

I'm trying to rebuild pycurl with OpenSSL because of [this bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=515200).
I use [this example](https://gist.github.com/aerickson/f15133a7e56b2d7f27e3):

> 1. sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot dpkg-dev
> 2. mkdir ~/python-pycurl-openssl
> 3. cd ~/python-pycurl-openssl
> 4. sudo apt-get source python-pycurl
> 5. sudo apt-get build-dep python-pycurl
> 6. sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
> 7. sudo dpkg-source -x pycurl_7.19.3-0ubuntu3.dsc
> 8. cd pycurl-7.19.3
> 9. edit debian/control file and replace all instances of    'libcurl4-gnutls-dev' with 'libcurl4-openssl-dev' (7 changes)
> 10. sudo PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b
> 11. sudo dpkg -i ../python-pycurl_7.19.3-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb

But after all I'm still stuck with GnuTLS build of pycurl.

```
>>> pycurl.version
'PycURL/7.19.5.1 libcurl/7.35.0 GnuTLS/2.12.23 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3'
```

Operation log (there are some error's tracebacks): http://pastebin.com/6hUEUGar

I use:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

I could solve the problem using pip:

```
sudo pip uninstall pycurl
export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl
sudo pip install pycurl --upgrade
```

Now:

```
>>> pycurl.version
'PycURL/7.19.5.1 libcurl/7.35.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3'
```

But I'm not sure It's right. Why are there two package in the system?
Or it's ok and python is just linked to one of them?

Comment: Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).